# VideoJS dynamically change source with initial type='application/x-mpegURL' in Windows 7 IE11

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-11, video.js

I am trying to dynamically change initially specified VideoJS source with  type='application/x-mpegURL'in Windows 7 IE11 (that doesn't support HLS stream) to supported one (type: "video/mp4") upon "VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED)" appearance. I was trying different approaches.
The best I could achieved is successfully change source to playable one.
However, even if the new source is initialized and could be played/paused the following issues still exist:

1.ProgressBar, vjs-duration/vjs-remaining-time does not update, showing duration/remaining time - “NONE” (even “player.duration()” shows correct value).

2.Progress control slider could not be dragged, current time could not be changed.

3.Play control(play/pause)doesn't update (always showing "play" icon regardless of "playing"/"paused" state).

HTML

```
<video id="video"  class="video-js vjs-default-skin "  width="640" height="360" poster="https://bitmovin-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/poster.png"  controls preload="auto" 
data-setup='{"liveui": true, "autoplay": false}'>
<source src="https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8", type='application/x-mpegURL' />
</video>
```

Case1:

```
 <script>
var player=videojs("video") 
player.on('error', function() {
console.log("error due to the unsupported format")
    //---attempt to change source
//player.reset();   
player.error(null);
player.src([
  { type: "video/mp4", src: "//vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" },
]); 
player.ready(function(){
player.on('loadedmetadata', function(){
console.log("player duration:",player.duration())
})});           
player.play();
});
</script>
```

[image: Result from Case:1]

Case:2

```
 <script>
var player=videojs("video") 
player.on('error', function() {
console.log("error due to the unsupported format")
    //---attempt to change source
//player.reset();   
//player.error(null);
player.src([
  { type: "video/mp4", src: "//vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" },
]); 
player.ready(function(){
player.on('loadedmetadata', function(){
console.log("player duration:",player.duration());
player.error(null);
})});           
player.play();
});
</script>
```

[image]

Case:3

```
    <script>
    var player=videojs("video") 
    player.on('error', function() {
    console.log("error due to the unsupported format")
        //---attempt to change source
    player.reset(); 
    //player.error(null);
    player.src([
      { type: "video/mp4", src: "//vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" },
    ]); 
    player.ready(function(){
    player.on('loadedmetadata', function(){
    console.log("player duration:",player.duration());
    //player.error(null);
    })});           
    player.play();
    });
    </script>
```

[image]

What wrong with my codes?

Video.js 7.6.5, Windows 7, IE11,

Answer (score 1):

This is confirmed video.js "bug".
https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/6256